HOW to generate SQL TRANSFORM, INNER JOIN and GROUP BY with database MS ACCESS IN VB.NET
I'm trying to generate SQL TRANSFORM, INNER JOIN and GROUP BY with database MS ACCESS in VB.NET.
I don't want to use functions in MS Access because I use SQL for VB.NET.
Is there any other method? Please guide me.
Thanks
TRANSFORM Max(ABSEN.TIME) AS MaxOfTIME
SELECT 
    ABSEN.ID AS ID, 
    MASTERID.NAMEID AS NAMEID, 
    MASTERID.LOCATION AS LOCATION, 
    ABSEN.DATE AS [DATE], 
    format(ABSEN.DATE,'dddd') AS DAYS, 
    ABSEN.STATUS AS STATUS, 
    ABSEN.INFO2 AS INFO2
FROM ABSEN 
    INNER JOIN MASTERID ON ABSEN.ID = MASTERID.ID
GROUP BY 
    ABSEN.ID, 
    MASTERID.NAMEID, 
    MASTERID.LOCATION, 
    ABSEN.DATE, 
    format(ABSEN.DATE,'dddd'), 
    ABSEN.STATUS, ABSEN.INFO2
PIVOT ABSEN.INOUT IN ('IN','OUT');

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class Form1
    Dim ABSENService As New ABSENService()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ABSENService.GetAllStatus.ToList()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ABSEN
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property NAMEID As String
    Public Property LOCATION As String
    Public Property [DATE] As DateTime
    Public Property DAYS As String
    Public Property DEFAULTIN As String
    Public Property DEFAULTOUT As String
    Public Property DEFAULTREST As String
    Public Property STATUS As String
    Public Property [IN] As String
    Public Property OUT As String
    Public Property DURATIONWORK As String
    Public Property LATE As String
    Public Property INFO2 As String
End Class
Public Class ABSENService
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIALABSEN.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Function GetAllStatus() As IEnumerable(Of ABSEN)
        Dim sql2 = <sql>
      TRANSFORM Max(ABSEN.TIME) AS MaxOfTIME
SELECT 
    ABSEN.ID AS ID, 
    MASTERID.NAMEID AS NAMEID, 
    MASTERID.LOCATION AS LOCATION, 
    ABSEN.DATE AS [DATE], 
    format(ABSEN.DATE,'dddd') AS DAYS, 
    ABSEN.STATUS AS STATUS, 
    ABSEN.INFO2 AS INFO2
FROM ABSEN 
    INNER JOIN MASTERID ON ABSEN.ID = MASTERID.ID
GROUP BY 
    ABSEN.ID, 
    MASTERID.NAMEID, 
    MASTERID.LOCATION, 
    ABSEN.DATE, 
    format(ABSEN.DATE,'dddd'), 
    ABSEN.STATUS, ABSEN.INFO2
PIVOT ABSEN.INOUT IN ('IN','OUT');
        </sql>.Value
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ABSEN)(sql2).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class

Table ABSEN



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT
STATUS
INFO2




1000
25-05-2024
08:00
IN
PRESENT



1000
25-05-2024
16:00
OUT
PRESENT



1000
26-05-2024

IN
NO PRESENT
NO WORK


1000
26-05-2024

OUT
NO PRESENT
NO WORK


1001
25-05-2024
08:00
IN
PRESENT



1001
25-05-2024
16:00
OUT
PRESENT



1001
26-05-2024

IN
NO PRESENT
NO WORK


1001
26-05-2024

OUT
NO PRESENT
NO WORK



Table MASTERDAYS



COMBINE
LOCATION
DAY
DEFAULTIN
DEFAULTOUT
DEFAULTREST




Asaturday
A
Saturday
08:00
15:30
01:00:00


Bsaturday
B
Saturday
07:30
15:00
01:00:00



Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
LOCATION




1000
JACK
A


1001
ROY
B



Result From code



ID
NAMEID
LOCATION
DATE
DAYS
DEFAULTIN
DEFAULTOUT
DEFAULTREST
STATUS
INFO2
IN
OUT
DURATIONWORK
LATE
INFO2




1000
JACK
A
25-05-2024
Saturday



PRESENT

08:00
16:00





1000
JACK
A
26-05-2024
Sunday



NO PRESENT
NO WORK







1001
ROY
B
25-05-2024
Saturday



PRESENT

08:00
16:00





1001
ROY
B
26-05-2024
Sunday



NO PRESENT
NO WORK








Desired output

Column DEFAULTIN, DEFAULTOUT AND DEFAULTREST FROM TABLE MASTERDAYS
Column DURATIONWORK (OUT-DEFAULTIN-DEFAULTREST)
Column LATE ((IN-DEFAULTIN)-(DEFAULTOUT-OUT)), For in < 08:00 and also out > 15:30 then the result is blank or empty in columns LATE




ID
NAMEID
LOCATION
DATE
DAYS
DEFAULTIN
DEFAULTOUT
DEFAULTREST
STATUS
IN
OUT
DURATIONWORK
LATE
INFO2




1000
JACK
A
25-05-2024
Saturday
08:00
15:30
01:00
PRESENT
08:10
15:25
06:15
00:15



1000
JACK
A
26-05-2024
Sunday



NO PRESENT




NO WORK


1001
ROY
B
25-05-2024
Saturday
07:30
15:00
01:00
PRESENT
08:00
16:00
07:00




1001
ROY
B
26-05-2024
Sunday



NO PRESENT




NO WORK



Desired output in image


Please stop using all-caps for everything - that's widely regarded as being equivalent to shouting.

@JonSkeet , thank you sorry I accidentally typed in this post

Are you using Dapper? If so, the class ABSEN should actually be used for desired output because its structure does not cover some ABSEN's fields (e.g. TIME, INOUT). And also, a tag for Dapper might be needed. And please do not use reserved words like DATE or IN as field names.

@ShahramAlemzadeh , sorry i'm late reply you. Are you using Dapper?  yes you are right and i also just updated the code in this post. If so, the class ABSEN should actually be used for desired output because its structure does not cover some ABSEN's fields (e.g. TIME, INOUT) sorry I previously i created desired output based on results in ms access query. And also, a tag for Dapper might be needed.  I've tagged just now. And please do not use reserved words like DATE or IN as field names For this I use brackets [ ] like this in the class . Please guide me via sql and linq dapper

@Tam88, please see this post which is similar to your question and may give you some idea: how-to-make-balance-column-calculations-from-stockcards-with-dapper-in-vb-net
